# How to set input focus on an INSERTED form in Drupal?

Tags: jquery, drupal, jquery-tools

I've got some code that uses the regular Forms API to put together a simple form. I'm using the jQuery Tools package to generate this form and insert it into an overlay. This is working fine, but I'd like to have the input focus set to a text field in the form once it's exposed. I've tried tacking some jQuery code that should do it --
`<script type='text/javascript'>$('#textfieldID').focus();</script>` -- or somesuch onto the end of the form in the form's theming function, but it's not getting loaded onto the page. I'm guessing this is because some part of Drupal is being "helpful" and filtering out the script, but I'm not really certain. In any case, the code's not getting run -- if I insert a javascript alert() statement as part of the code, nothing happens.

Any advice out there? I'd really like to get the focus set on this guy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm declaring this to be "answered" -- after digging deeper (= blood on the keyboard), it's now clear to me that jQuery Tools is the culprit here -- the form, as created by Drupal, definitely contains whatever scripting stuff I insert into it (latest scheme: a $(document).ready(...focus...) as a markup element in the form).  Somewhere in making its way through the jQT overlay process, the scripting goes away.  The main hint: If I disable the overlay such that the form comes up in a regular page, the script is present, runs, and correctly sets the focus.

Blurg; at least I (think I) know what's going on -- even though it's not working, I've got a better question to ask.  Thanks to all for the help along the way.

Comment: FINAL update(!): I now have it working. I'm using the method in the post immediately above here -- putting the script into the form as the value of a markup item. What changed was the way I got the form contents back from the PHP code. I was initially following the jQT example a little too literally, and (cf the jQT example) using a .load() statement to call out to the server, get the page containing the form, finding the form in that page, and inserting it. I changed this bit of the code to do an .ajax() call to the server to just get the form, and now all's well. Thanks again to all!

Answer (score 1):

You should use Drupal's api to include the JavaScript, using [`drupal_add_js`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_js/6). Doing it in the form's theming function is the way to go, since it would be called, even if the form is cached.

Drupal won't filter out script tags etc, so if they aren't printed, it sounds like you are doing something wrong in your theming function.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I think there's something else going on here.  (1) The issue, I think, is that the form is getting on the screen by my getting the form contents in a Javascript function and doing an ajax call that sticks the form a jQuery Tools overlay, without doing a page refresh.  As far as I know, drupal_add_js() will see that the specified javascript will get loaded the next time the page loads, but that's not the situation I'm in.  In any case, I tried it, with no luck. ...

Comment: (2) I got a little fancier with the stuff I'm sending into the overlay, and tried something like this -- <div id='outer'><div id='theform'> …form stuff..</div><script>alert('hi')</script><div id='more stuff'>hi there</div></div>.  That is, one big div with two inner divs and the hard-coded script tag.  When I check the contents of the form on the screen, both content divs are there but the script is not.  Weird.  Maybe it's a jQuery Tools issue?

Comment: @Jim M: If you are getting the form via AJAX, you should add the js to what's already on the page. A callback to the ajax. In this case drupal_add_js wont work. If you load the form with the page, the problem is most likely that your theme function isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do drupal_add_js in the form theme functions, but I would need to see your code.

This works for me:

```
mymodule_init() {
   if (request_uri() == 'path where your form resides') {
      drupal_add_js(arguments);
   }
}
```

If you have a multistep form, you can do this:

```
mymodule_init() {
   if (preg_match('/path/', request_uri())) {
      drupal_add_js(arguments);
   }
}
```

You might want to use drupal_match_path instead of preg_match above, but I have been unsuccessful in getting that to work for this scenario.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/6

Comment: This can quickly become messy, especially if the form is used on multiple pages. I prefer using the form's theming function, since it will be called regardless of URL. In many cases this will work fine though.

Comment: Yep. Just offering an alternative, no source code was posted in the question.